# How to write a twitter regex expression?

Tags: regex

I need a twitter expression:

```
twitter.com\/[\w\/\.=-]*
```

This one works fine, except it does capture generic twitter widgets.js library

I would like to capture ALL twitter.com **EXCEPT those who cantain "widgets.js"** (using regex)

ex:

```
twitter.com/myaccount: GOOD
twitter.com/JohnDOes: GOOD
twitter.com/widgets.js: BAD
```

Regards

Comment: Do you also have things like `twitter.com/custom/widgets.js` that you don't want to capture?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a negative lookahead:

```
twitter.com\/(?!widgets\.js)[\w\/\.=-]*
```

Depending on whether you are matching part of a larger text or individual strings, you may want to add some anchors:

```
^twitter.com\/(?!widgets\.js$)[\w\/\.=-]*$
```

Comment: You might want to escape the period in the negative lookahead. Just to be exact.